# How to list all Microsoft CA Certificate templates with oid in c#

Tags: c#, certificate

I am trying to retrieve All enrollable Certificate templates in Microsoft CA. I can able to do it with powershell command "Get-CATemplate". I wanted to do it in c# without using powershell commands

Answer (score 0):

The list of all enrollable Certificate templates in Microsoft CA can be retrieved by using `ICertRequest2` COM interface. There is a `GetCAProperty` method available in this interface.

You will have to add a reference to `CertCli` COM library.

[image]

Then use `CCertRequest` class which implements `ICertRequest` interface. The method returns string value in the following format: `TemplateName1\nTemplateOID1\nTemplateName2\nTemplateOID2\....` You can split this string with \n .In below example I'm selecting template name only.

```
    private const int CR_PROP_TEMPLATES = 0x0000001D;
    private const int PROPTYPE_STRING = 0x00000004;
    public void GetTemplates(string CAServer)
    {
        try
        {
            var objCertRequest = new CCertRequest();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"([A-Za-z]+)");
            string templateString = objCertRequest.GetCAProperty(CAServer, CR_PROP_TEMPLATES, 0, PROPTYPE_STRING, 0);
            string[] templates = Regex.Split(templateString, @"\n");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

For more details about `GetCAProperty` [Click Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249749.aspx)